# How do I edit a question to make it better?

Tags: discussion, editing

I think "[Why are most math textbooks so uninspiring; unless you already like Math?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/2123/why-are-most-math-textbooks-so-uninspiring-unless-you-already-like-math)" is a good question. It's closed because 5 people marked it "unclear what you're asking". I'd like to edit it to make it a good question.

It sounds like the first thing is to ask a slightly different question - instead of why, to ask something else about these uninspiring textbooks. I do think that textbooks are often bad at engaging readers. We could ask what textbooks have helped people enter the world of math and how they're different from the average textbook. We could ask what principles would help authors write better textbooks. Or ...?

Can anyone help me with ideas about what would make this question acceptable?

Comment: On the technical point (I assume this is what you meant with "did I do this right?"): while the syntax for comment notifications is mainly correct, it is not possible to use comment notification in this way; the closers will not receive a notification. The @user only has an effect in comments (not in posts). In addition,  one can only comment-notify users active on a post, specifically those users that already commented on a post or edited the post (and a *moderator* that closed). On the syntax: space should be omitted not replaced by underscore; so MarkFantini but first >= 3 letters suffice.

Comment: Thanks, quid. So, is there any way to ask those 5 to participate? I have deleted them from the post.

Comment: There is no really feasible way  to do this; except maybe for one that commented on the original post; there you could write a comment there on the main post notifying of the meta post. The moderator-tool to contact users would theoretically work but I would advise against using this here  as this tool is rather reserved for more drastic situations. I would just wait, I assume some of them will see the post. Even if not, if there is some other community input this is also fine.  (I might write something on the question itself a bit later.)

Comment: In my opinion a main problem with the question "as is" is that the tone is still a bit rant-y. One thing I would propose to do is to change this. Generally, I would cut down the text in the question, and preserve only what is needed for the answers to keep making sense. The questions you propose are interesting, but I would propose to rather make new question-posts (possibly linking the old one) than adding to the old one.

Comment: I took out a bit, and changed a word or two. It does still sound like a rant, but it seems like a useful rant. As a closed question, it will stay there, and can be referred to? It just can't get more answers? I will try to write a new question related to this. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I think it is better now. On your questions: yes and yes. (In more detail, the main effect of closing is that new answers are blocked, yet voting editing commenting all stay possible. The question even retains basically the same visibility. Closing can in principle  be a step towards [auto] deletion; but for automatic deletion the score of question and answers needs to be low, and I highly doubt the question will be manually deleted by votes of 3 users. Even then it could still be undeleted.)